# Jquery: Changing an element's ID by clicking on the element itself, then having it change back by clicking on the element again

Tags: jquery, attributes, click, element

I am trying to change an element's ID by clicking on the element using Jquery. The operation works on the first click, but not any clicks afterward.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#chatframebuttonhidden").click(function() {
var $t = $(this);
            $t.attr({
                    id : $t.attr('id2')
                });
            });;
$("#chatframebuttonshown").click(function() {
var $t = $(this);
            $t.attr({
                    id : $t.attr('id1')
                });
            });;
});


<div id="chatframebuttonhidden" id2="chatframebuttonshown" id1="chatframebuttonhidden"></div>
```

The term "hidden" doesn't mean the div is out of view, it just means it's much smaller and less noticeable.

The ultimate goal is to make a button that hides/unhides a large fixed position divider on the bottom of the screen. I think that changing the ID so it references a new stylesheet is the best method, but if you guys know a better method I'm all ears.

Comment: As the answers suggest, using a class is more approriate, but for your information the click handler is not unbound even if you change the ID, so you can just do this -> [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dj2nG/), to change the ID, all though it is generally a bad idea to do so.

Comment: `The term "hidden" doesn't mean the div is out of view, it just means it's much smaller and less noticeable.` but then you say `The ultimate goal is to make a button that hides/unhides a large fixed position divider on the bottom of the screen.` Which is it? Make the div smaller/bigger or hide/unhide it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a class instead and toggle it on and off. IDs aren't really meant to be changed like that, classes are.

Also no need to swap out the entire stylesheet to hide some elements. Use a parent container and hide that.

Comment: Can this be used to change a style attribute? I want to toggle between:
    
    background-position:0px -20px;

and

    background-position:0px 0px;

Comment: I wouldn't change the style attribute directly. One way would be to put those 2 styles on different classes and toggle them on and off.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery `toggle`:

```
$("#chatframebutton").click(function() {
 $('#chatframe').toggle();
});
```

No need to juggle classes or ids for this use case.

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use class instead of ids to change stylesheet properties.

```
$(#chatframebutton).toggleClass(chatframebuttonshownhidden);
```

where chatframebuttonshownhidden is described in your stylesheet

checkout http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/ for more details.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you use classes or Id's to change stylesheet styles

Comment: I believe it matters, because using class gives u a certain abstraction, on the contrary, id is very specific. Take for example I have 100 buttons on a page, and I want to change the style of all buttons with one click, would I write a css with 100 ids, or just one class ?

Comment: Aye, I would include this in your answer you also have a small type of '' around the selector